# MissingMethod: no signature for arguemnt type java.util.LinkedHashMap, possible solutions: java.util.LinkedHashMap)

Tags: groovy

I am trying to pass a pass a set of named arguments into a method.
I can pass the arguments to a function, but not to a method.
When I run this code:

```
class Tester {
    def exectute(java.util.LinkedHashMap tests) {
        println("Tests are ${tests}")
    }
}

def funct(def test)
{
    println "Test is ${test}"
}

def arg=[:]
arg['CASE 1'] = [ script: "test.sh", log: false]

def testclass = new Tester()
println "${arg}"
funct(arg)
testclass.execute(arg)
```

I get the response below:

```
[CASE 1:[script:test.sh, log:false]]
Test is [CASE 1:[script:test.sh, log:false]]
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Tester.execute()     
is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: 
[[CASE  1:[script:test.sh, log:false]]]
Possible solutions: exectute(java.util.LinkedHashMap)
at ConsoleScript17.run(ConsoleScript17:21)
```

Any suggestions how I could fix this?

I am probably missing something trivial as I am inexperienced in groovy and java.

Comment: You have a typo in your method name `exectute`. And you call one without spelling issues (`execute`).

Comment: The groovy exception shows you both spellings (if you look at the _"Possible solutions"_ bit)

Comment: You can use the `@TypeChecked` or `@CompileStatic` Annotations to avoid such mistakes in the future.

Comment: Thanks all, awfully stupid of me. I will look into the annotations.